# How to fertilize strawberries in containers?

Tags: fertilizer, strawberries

I have strawberries in containers and i want to fertilize them. What is the best approch and what type of fetilizer do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Mix fertilizer into the potting medium if it does not already contain it. Do this before filling the container. Use a slow release fertilizer -- such as one labeled as Osmocote, 15-9-12 or 10-10-10 -- and mix it evenly into the soil. Since fertilizer rates vary, apply according to label instructions.